# Sorting numerically by character field position within field

Tags: sort

I have an extract from a forward DNS zone file, which I want to sort by ascending IP address. Before you mark this as a duplicate, please read on a short while, because this isn't about sorting IP addresses as such (`sort -k5V` would address that).

Here is a sample of the data:

```
esx01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.212
ilo01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.211
nas01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.101
pc001.example.com.      1200    IN      A       10.1.1.42
pc002.example.com.      1200    IN      A       10.1.1.52
pc003.example.com.      1200    IN      A       10.1.1.29
```

In this specific case I know I can sort by just the last octet, so this should be a straightforward application of `sort`.

The man page confirms that I can use `-k` with not only a field but also an offset within that field, and with an `n` numeric modifier

> `KEYDEF` is `F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]` for start and stop position, where `F` is a field number and `C` a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end. If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from the beginning of  the preceding  whitespace. `OPTS` is one or more single-letter ordering options [`bdfgiMhnRrV`], which override global ordering options for that key.

The last octet conveniently starts at character offset eight within the fifth field, so my understanding is that this command should suffice:

```
sort -k5.8n /tmp/axfr.10.1.1
```

However, this does not sort my data at all. Empirically I find I need to start at field position **15** to sort this data in ascending numeric order as expected:

```
sort -k5.15n /tmp/axfr.10.1.1

pc003.example.com.      1200    IN      A       10.1.1.29
pc001.example.com.      1200    IN      A       10.1.1.42
pc002.example.com.      1200    IN      A       10.1.1.52
nas01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.101
ilo01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.211
esx01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.212
```

Why?

Comment: GNU `sort`'s `-V` option is useful to sort quad-decimal IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `sort --debug` option to get some clues:

```
$ echo 'esx01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.212' | 
   sort --debug -k5.8n
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: leading blanks are significant in key 1; consider also specifying 'b'
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
esx01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.212
                                                ____
```

It is underlining the sort field. It isn't what you expected.
You need `-b`, as sort counts columns from the end of the previous field
(man page: *If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a  field  are counted  from  the beginning of the preceding whitespace*):

```
$ ... | sort --debug -b -n -k5.8 
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
esx01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.212
                                                       ___
```

The `-n` needs to be separate:

```
$ ... | sort --debug -b -k5.8n
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: leading blanks are significant in key 1; consider also specifying 'b'
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
sort: option '-b' is ignored
esx01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.212
                                                ____
```

or the `b` given with the `n`:

```
$ ... | sort --debug  -k5.8nb
sort: using simple byte comparison
sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields
esx01.example.com.      3600    IN      A       10.1.1.212
                                                       ___
```

Comment: Why does `sort --debug -b -k5.8n` warn that `option '-b' is ignored`?

Comment: It may have to do with compatibility with older versions. `info sort` for gnu sort says: *According to POSIX, '-n' no longer implies '-b'*, so perhaps `n` in `-k` used to undo `-b`.

Comment: Mmm. `sort -b -k5.10` is permitted, but `sort -b -k5.10n` is not. And for my data set `sort -nb -k5.10` complains that, `sort: key 1 is numeric and spans multiple fields`. The whole concept of a sort field beginning with the field's preceding whitespace doesn't make any sense to me whatsoever, though.

Comment: @roaima, the default field separator is the transition between a non-blank and a blank. The fact that `sort -bk5.8n` doesn't work (when `sort -bnk5.8` and `sort -k5.8bn` work) sounds like a bug to me (but then it seems to be affecting  all implementations, so I may be missing something)

Comment: gnu's `info sort` says *A position in a sort field specified with '-k' may have any of the option letters 'MbdfghinRrV' appended to it, in which case no global
ordering options are inherited by that particular field.*

Comment: @meuh - yeah, the same info page does state that "the global options _are inherited by key fields that do not specify any special options of their own_" so  `-bnk5.8` works because the key field has no options of its own whereas `-bk5.8n` doesn't work since the key field already has the `n` option so `-b` isn't inherited.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, POSIX does say it as well. I hadn't realised that (or if I did, I forgot ;-))

Comment: Ah. Good catches, thank you all. That's been most enlightening.

Comment: And here's the corresponding text from the man page, « `OPTS` is one or more single-letter ordering options [`bdfgiMhnRrV`], _which override global ordering options for that key_. » I think I'd have been more likely to have spotted this if it had said « override _all_ global ordering options... ».

Answer (score 0):

When sort's (or anything's) field specs are running out of steam, getting hard to construct and decipher and debug, it can be more productive and clearer to preprocess the data:

```
awk -F. '{print $NF"\t"$0}' | sort -snk1,1 | cut -f2-
```

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't address the question I'm asking. (Which is not how to sort the data, but why `sort` doesn't behave as I expect.)

Comment: I've found that people, me included, will often enough attempt a bad solution to a problem and ask for help implementing their solution rather than fixing their problem.  So it is here: your question is about how to do the wrong thing. Even once you get your index right your code will still be awfully fragile.

Comment: The best solution for the sorting task turns out to be `sort -k5V`, but the question isn't about how to sort IP addresses, it's why `sort` wasn't working the way I expected. My sample data happened to be the output from `dig axfr...` but it could equally have been from some other source. I had hoped my second sentence of the question would have made that quite clear; I've extended that even more explicitly, now.